# The document "(null)" requires Xcode 6.0 or later

Tags: storyboard, xcode6

I have opened storyboard file in Xcode 6.0.1 edited, put some autolayout constraints and save it. then i tried it to open in Xcode5.1 but not able to open Storyboard file in XCode5.1, even i have set deploy-able Xcode version to Xcode5.1. But Xcode showing error "Require Xcode6.0 or later".!

Comment: may be you have enabled size classes, which are not supported by xcode 5, haven't you?

Comment: Thanks, i revert back constraints and put it back in Xcode5.1.1 and it works. Xcode6 automatically applied size constraints and updated document min version to 6.0.

Comment: Maybe this is a proper answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26001749/3003687