# The document “(null)” requires Xcode 8.0 or later

Tags: storyboard, xcode8

I saw a similar question for 6.0

[Building a project in Xcode5.1 that was modified in Xcode 6 GM for testing older versions of iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846600/building-a-project-in-xcode5-1-that-was-modified-in-xcode-6-gm-for-testing-older/26001749#26001749)

The solution there was to look at the storyboard source and find where the constraints were set to the margin and not the superview and change that. I looked through my source code in 8.0 a and did a search for constraint but didn't find any.

Is there something else that can throw this error?

Comment: More details please. How says "The document “(null)” requires Xcode 8.0 or later" by doing what in which Xcode version aso.

Comment: I'm actually running XC8.1. Doing nothing but trying to build it.

Answer (score 8):

We can solve this Using Xcode 7 , right-click on the file(xib or storyboard) and open as source code. Then search ( Command + F ) for: minToolsVersion="8.0"and change it to 7.0.

Then open the file as interface builder xib document.

(Reference from https://github.com/istornz/iPokeGo/issues/68)

Answer (score 4):

```
    I am also facing this issue, when i open in Xcode  8 and try to open in Xcode  7.  finally i found solution  , fallow below steps.


    1) Select Storyboard file (iPhone or iPad)
    2) Right click ==> open as source code
    3) change  <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
to

<capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 7 format" minToolsVersion="7.0"/>

    4) Run code it will work
```

Answer (score 3):

The Smith's answer is not enough, you have to remove also the section

```
< device >...< / device >
```

and the section

```
< simulatedMetricsContainer >...< / simulatedMetricsContainer >
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this by deleting my derived data. FYI, in XC8 derived data is no longer accessible from the Project submenu under the Window menu, the Project submenu has been removed.

You can now find the derived data under File --> Project Settings. You cannot delete from here but the arrow button next to the path will open the file in the Finder. You can delete it from there.